# How to analyze a multi-module project with Eclipse SonarQube plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have a multi-module project (java and js modules). I'm trying to use the Eclipse Sonar plugin. Is this supported? If so, how?

I can link my project to a Sonar project, but I cannot link it to the specific module of interest. When I run, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://myserver:9000/api/sources?resource=myProjectKey:com.MyClass&amp;format=txt]. Response code: 500
```

The above error happens because the project key should be `myProjectKey:java`. Modifying `sonar.projectKey` in the Eclipse plugin has no effect.

If I try to set `sonar.modules=java` and then set all the other settings for Java, then nothing gets analyzed by Sonar because a multi-module project cannot have sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define a multi-module structure in SonarQube:

1. Set all the configuration in the properties file in the root folder
2. Set the configuration in multiple properties files

just follow this url: 
[AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject)

Comment: I'm using 1 and I have everything working with SonarQubeRunner on my CI server. But how do I also get it working with the Eclipse plugin?